# Incorrect time saved during event execution

Tags: mysql, events

I have an event which saves data to table:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`i2` EVENT `AcrhiveData` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 5 
                MINUTE STARTS '2017-03-13 10:45:00' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE DO
INSERT INTO `archived`(`projectNo`, `staff_id`, `longname`, `username`, `title`, `process`, `creation_time`)   
SELECT a.*
FROM
(
    (
        SELECT p.projectNo,
               usr.staff_id,
               usr.longname,
               usr.username,
               p.title,
               CONCAT(upr.process, " (", upr.role, ")" ) AS process,
               NOW() AS creation_time
        FROM project p
        INNER JOIN user_project upr
            ON p.projectNo = upr.projectNo
        INNER JOIN user usr
            ON upr.username = usr.username
        WHERE EXISTS (SELECT status FROM check_change WHERE status = "1" )
    )
) AS a
ORDER BY a.projectNo
```

it works but the problem is incorrect time in `NOW()`. if i save it at `2017-03-29-10:50:00` on my pc event will save it as `2017-03-29 02:50:00`
What is the problem and how can I solve this?

Comment: @Forward it is +08:00

Comment: are you working with one PC only, I mean your database too.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should reset your timezone for mysql:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+08:00';
```

#### Edit:


Try this:

```
SET time_zone = '+08:00';
INSERT INTO `archived`(`projectNo`, `staff_id`, `longname`, `username`, `title`, `process`, `creation_time`)
SELECT a.*
......
```

Comment: Is there a way to integrate it inside my event?

Comment: Did you mean before  `INSERT `? anyway i put it both ways cant run an event as it gives me error

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Sorry, my bad, it's shoud be before `insert`, what is your error?

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO `archived`(`projectNo`, `staff_id`, `longname`, `username`, `title`,' at line 2`

Comment: @YevgeniyBagackiy Did you miss `;` after set statement?

Answer (score 0):

ok, thats how i solved the problem:

instead of `NOW() AS creation_time` I used `DATE_ADD(UTC_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR) AS creation_time`